# issue with password_verify()

Tags: php

So i am a newbie in php.
I have database with a pseudo and pwd table, the passwords are crypted with password_hash.
This is how i send new user in my database :

```
<?php
$options = [
'cost' => 8,
'salt' => mcrypt_create_iv(22, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM),
];

$pwd = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);

$insert_query = "insert into user values ('$pseudo','$pwd','$mail')";

$mysqli->query($insert_query);
```

It's working, then when i want to log as user wich is in the database, i searh the password associated with the pseudo i write in the form, once i have the password i use it with the noon crypted password (the one i get by POST)

```
$options = [
'cost' => 8,
'salt' => mcrypt_create_iv(22, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM),
];

$pwd2 = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);

$sql_log = "select mdp from user where pseudo ='$pseudo'";

$mysqli->multi_query($sql_log);

if($res = $mysqli->use_result()) {

    while($row = $res->fetch_row()) {
        echo $row[0]."<br/>";   
    }
    $res->close();
    echo $pwd2."<br/>";
    echo $pwd."<br/>";

    if(password_verify($pwd,$row[0])) {
        $mysqli->close();
        $_SESSION['pseudo'] = $pseudo;

        die("<script>location.href = 'homepage.php'</script>");
    }
    else 
        echo "putin";
}
```

But it's not working, ive read other topics about it but nothing helps me.

Comment: Are there any errors ? Enable your error reporting with error_reporting(E_ALL) Where are defined your $pseudo and $mail variables?

Comment: pseudo and pwd are defined in log.php like this :
$pseudo = $_POST['pseudo'];
$pwd = $_POST['pwd'];
but as i said the data i send to my database are correct

Comment: edit with var_dump($pwd2) and var_dump($pwd)

Answer (score 1):

Ok i've found my problem, i don't know if it will be usefull for others or if i make understandable but i was really dumb.

```
while($row = $res->fetch_row()) {
    echo $row[0]."<br/>";   
}
$res->close();
echo $pwd2."<br/>";
echo $pwd."<br/>";

if(password_verify($pwd,$row[0])) {
    $mysqli->close();
    $_SESSION['pseudo'] = $pseudo;

    die("<script>location.href = 'homepage.php'</script>");
}
```

i created row in the while and when i check his value out of the while it returns 0, so the second argument that i was passing in password_verify was null...

ty